# Spark 2.x scala 2.1.1 custom encoder class type mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, rtti

I am using this code to define an encoder for spark 2.x, in scala 2.1.1:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

class LogProcessorMessageEncoder extends Encoder[LogProcessorMessage] {
    override def schema: StructType = null

    override def clsTag: Class[LogProcessorMessage] = classOf[LogProcessorMessage]
}

object LogProcessorMessage {}

class LogProcessorMessage extends Serializable {}
```

And IntelliJ says it is fine, but the override of the clsTag method results in a compiler error:

```
Error:(20, 15) overriding method clsTag in trait Encoder of type => scala.reflect.ClassTag[dvn.aast.telemetry.scala.stream.LogProcessorMessage];
method clsTag has incompatible type
override def clsTag: Class[LogProcessorMessage] = classOf[LogProcessorMessage]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clsTag` has to be `ClassTag` not `Class`:

```
class LogProcessorMessageEncoder extends Encoder[LogProcessorMessage] {
  override def clsTag: ClassTag[LogProcessorMessage] = ClassTag(classOf[LogProcessorMessage])
  override def schema: StructType = null 
}
```

Comment: You can write this as just `classTag[LogProcessorMessage]` (just import `classTag` along with `ClassTag`).

Comment: Thank you both very much!  The original def was generated by IntelliJ - I should have looked at the return type more closely.  Thanks a bunch.